# Set NULL using a CallableStatement

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, callable-statement

I m using JDBC With sql server 2008. I have a column in the table that the type is "decimal(18, 2)". I want to insert a null value to this column using  "CallableStatement". How do i do that?

i tried `callstmt.setNull(14, java.sql.Types.DECIMAL);`. but that does not work.

HTTP Status 404 - /NSBMHCGcom.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:%20Error%20converting%20data%20type%20nvarchar%20to%20numeric./eHRMS_AR_M_display_SetupOTConditions

### This is the error I am getting.

type Status report

message /NSBMHCGcom.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:%20Error%20converting%20data%20type%20nvarchar%20to%20numeric./eHRMS_AR_M_display_SetupOTConditions

description The requested resource (/NSBMHCGcom.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:%20Error%20converting%20data%20type%20nvarchar%20to%20numeric./eHRMS_AR_M_display_SetupOTConditions) is not available.

**This is the part of a code.**

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO " + m_schema_name + ".[AR_M_OTConditions] ([ConditionDescription],[StartHour],[EndHour]"
                        + " ,[Day],[IsActive],"
                        + "[EntDate],[EntUser],[ModDate],[ModUser],[Rate],[MinOT],[MaxOT],[EmpCategory],[EmpType],[Condition],[MinHour],[MaxHour],[Amount]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,getDate(),?,getDate(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                callstmt = conn.prepareCall(strSQL);
                callstmt.setString(1, m_con_methods.met_formdata(reqstr, "TXT_LEVELNAME"));
                callstmt.setString(2, m_con_methods.met_formdata(reqstr, "TXT_FROM"));
                callstmt.setString(3, m_con_methods.met_formdata(reqstr, "TXT_TO"));
                callstmt.setString(4, m_con_methods.met_formdata(reqstr, "TXT_FINYEAR"));
                callstmt.setBoolean(5, true);
                callstmt.setString(6, m_username);
                callstmt.setString(7, m_username);
                callstmt.setString(8, m_con_methods.met_formdata(reqstr, "TXT_RATE"));
                callstmt.setString(9, m_con_methods.met_formdata(reqstr, "TXT_MIN") );
                callstmt.setString(10, m_con_methods.met_formdata(reqstr, "TXT_MAX"));
                callstmt.setString(11, m_con_methods.met_formdata(reqstr, "TXT_CHARGABLE_STATUS"));
                callstmt.setString(12, m_con_methods.met_formdata(reqstr, "TXT_TYPE"));
                callstmt.setString(13, m_con_methods.met_formdata(reqstr, "TXT_CONDITIONS"));
                callstmt.setNull(14, java.sql.Types.DECIMAL);
                callstmt.setString(15, m_con_methods.met_formdata(reqstr, "TXT_MAX_HOUR"));
                callstmt.setString(16, m_con_methods.met_formdata(reqstr, "TXT_CONDITIONS_AMOUNT"));
```

====================================================================================================

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.warn
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "warn".
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 6.0.18\logs\NSBM.log (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:192)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:116)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:290)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:164)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:257)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:133)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:97)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:689)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:647)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:544)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:476)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:471)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:125)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:105)
    at pwc.ehrms.common.CommonConnections.LogSystemErrors(CommonConnections.java:633)
    at pwc.ehrms.master.eHRMS_AR_M_save_SetupOTConditions.service(eHRMS_AR_M_save_SetupOTConditions.java:165)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

====================================================================================================

Comment: `does not work` is neither a valid SQL Server error message nor a Java compiler error. You need to be more specific. Also: a `CallableStatement` is for running stored procedures. Do you want to pass `NULL` as a procedure parameter?

Comment: Show the actual exception + stacktrace instead of the HTTP error.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have a package who has an input type object and an output type object

```
CustomInputType customInputType = transform(customView);
final String query = "{?=call SCHEMA_DBA.PRJ_PKG_CUSTOM.FUNC_CUSTOM_X(?)}";
fdb.setUpCallable(query);
final Map<String, Class<?>> typeMap = fdb.getConnection().getTypeMap();
typeMap.put("SCHEMA_DBA.TY_CUSTOM_INPUT", Class.forName("com.myproject.view.CustomInputType"));
typeMap.put("SCHEMA_DBA.FI_TY_CUSTOM_OUTPUT", Class.forName("com.myproject.view.CustomOutputType"));
typeMap.put("TY_CUSTOM_INPUT", Class.forName("com.myproject.view.CustomInputType"));
typeMap.put("FI_TY_CUSTOM_OUTPUT", Class.forName("com.myproject.view.CustomOutputType"));
fdb.getCallableStatement().registerOutParameter(1, Types.STRUCT, "SCHEMA_DBA.FI_TY_CUSTOM_OUTPUT");
fdb.getCallableStatement().setObject(2, customInputType);
fdb.executeCallable();
CustomOutputType customOutputType = (CustomOutputType) callableStatement.getObject(1);
CustomOutput customOutput = valorizzaCaricaLineeDiFido(customOutputType);
```

in the CustomInputType you must have

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.SQLData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLInput;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;

public class CustomInputType implements SQLData {

    String sql_type = "SCHEMA_DBA.TY_CUSTOM_INPUT";

    String inputStringX;
    Long inputLongY;
    Date inputDataZ;
    Double inputDoubleW;

    public String getInputStringX() {
        return inputStringX;
    }

    public void setInputStringX(String inputStringX) {
        this.inputStringX = inputStringX;
    }

    public Long getInputLongY() {
        return inputLongY;
    }

    public void setInputLongY(Long inputLongY) {
        this.inputLongY = inputLongY;
    }

    public Date getInputDataZ() {
        return inputDataZ;
    }

    public void setInputDataZ(Date inputDataZ) {
        this.inputDataZ = inputDataZ;
    }

    public Double getInputDoubleW() {
        return inputDoubleW;
    }

    public void setInputDoubleW(Double inputDoubleW) {
        this.inputDoubleW = inputDoubleW;
    }

    // -- sqlType -- v
    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
        return sql_type;
    }

    public String getSqlType() {
        return sql_type;
    }
    // -- sqlType -- ^

    // -- read/write Data utility-- v
    public Long readDataLong(SQLInput stream) throws SQLException {
        Long dataLong = stream.readLong();
        if (stream.wasNull()) {
            dataLong = null;
        }
        return dataLong;
    }

    public Double readDataDouble(SQLInput stream) throws SQLException {
        Double dataDouble = stream.readDouble();
        if (stream.wasNull()) {
            dataDouble = null;
        }
        return dataDouble;
    }

    public void writeDataLong(SQLOutput stream, Long dataLong) throws SQLException {
        if (dataLong != null) {
            stream.writeLong(dataLong);
        } else {
            stream.writeObject(null);
        }
    }

    public void writeDataDouble(SQLOutput stream, Double dataDouble) throws SQLException {
        if (dataDouble != null) {
            stream.writeDouble(dataDouble);
        } else {
            stream.writeObject(null);
        }
    }
    // -- read/write Data utility-- ^

    @Override
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        this.sql_type = typeName;
        this.inputStringX = stream.readString();
        this.inputLongY = readDataLong(stream);
        this.inputDataZ = stream.readDate();
        this.inputDoubleW = readDataDouble(stream);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
        stream.writeString(this.inputStringX);
        writeDataLong(stream, this.inputLongY);
        stream.writeDate(this.inputDataZ);
        writeDataDouble(stream, this.inputDoubleW);
    }
```

in the CustomOutputType we have

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.SQLData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLInput;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;

public class CustomOutputType implements SQLData {

    String sql_type = "SCHEMA_DBA.TY_CUSTOM_OUTPUT";

    String inputStringA;
    Long inputLongB;
    Date inputDataC;
    Double inputDoubleD;

    public String getInputStringA() {
        return inputStringA;
    }

    public void setInputStringA(String inputStringA) {
        this.inputStringA = inputStringA;
    }

    public Long getInputLongB() {
        return inputLongB;
    }

    public void setInputLongB(Long inputLongB) {
        this.inputLongB = inputLongB;
    }

    public Date getInputDataC() {
        return inputDataC;
    }

    public void setInputDataC(Date inputDataC) {
        this.inputDataC = inputDataC;
    }

    public Double getInputDoubleD() {
        return inputDoubleD;
    }

    public void setInputDoubleD(Double inputDoubleD) {
        this.inputDoubleD = inputDoubleD;
    }

    // -- sqlType -- v
    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
        return sql_type;
    }

    public String getSqlType() {
        return sql_type;
    }
    // -- sqlType -- ^

    // -- read/write Data utility-- v
    public Long readDataLong(SQLInput stream) throws SQLException {
        Long dataLong = stream.readLong();
        if (stream.wasNull()) {
            dataLong = null;
        }
        return dataLong;
    }

    public Double readDataDouble(SQLInput stream) throws SQLException {
        Double dataDouble = stream.readDouble();
        if (stream.wasNull()) {
            dataDouble = null;
        }
        return dataDouble;
    }

    public void writeDataLong(SQLOutput stream, Long dataLong) throws SQLException {
        if (dataLong != null) {
            stream.writeLong(dataLong);
        } else {
            stream.writeObject(null);
        }
    }

    public void writeDataDouble(SQLOutput stream, Double dataDouble) throws SQLException {
        if (dataDouble != null) {
            stream.writeDouble(dataDouble);
        } else {
            stream.writeObject(null);
        }
    }
    // -- read/write Data utility-- ^

    @Override
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        this.sql_type = typeName;
        this.inputStringA = stream.readString();
        this.inputLongB = readDataLong(stream);
        this.inputDataC = stream.readDate();
        this.inputDoubleD = readDataDouble(stream);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
        stream.writeString(this.inputStringA);
        writeDataLong(stream, this.inputLongB);
        stream.writeDate(this.inputDataC);
        writeDataDouble(stream, this.inputDoubleD);
    }
```

Considerations:

1. Output object use the declaration

   typeMap.put("SCHEMA_DBA.FI_TY_CUSTOM_OUTPUT", Class.forName("com.myproject.view.CustomOutputType"));

to understand what is the data object to use
2) Input object use the declaration
public class CustomInputType implements SQLData {

```
String sql_type = "SCHEMA_DBA.TY_CUSTOM_INPUT";
```

to understand what is the data object to use
3) for getting NULL for Stream SQLInput you can do it like this

Long dataLong = stream.readLong();

```
if (stream.wasNull()) {
    dataLong = null;
}
```

so readLong return 0 if is NULL in database but after with wasNull you can force the value in java back to null if in database is in fact NULL

4. for setting NULL for Stream SQLOutput you can do it like this

   if (dataLong != null) {
   stream.writeLong(dataLong);
   } else {
   stream.writeObject(null);
   }

so if the value is not null then you can use writeLong with long, but if the value is null in java you must use writeObject with null parameter to set NULL in database

cheers